# Python's document about MRO is wrong?

Tags: python, method-resolution-order

I read this doc today. There is something confused me.

http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/

In the example to prove the MRO of Python 2.2 breaks monotonicity,

```
>>> class A(object): pass
>>> class B(object): pass
>>> class C(object): pass
>>> class D(object): pass
>>> class E(object): pass
>>> class K1(A,B,C): pass
>>> class K2(D,B,E): pass
>>> class K3(D,A):   pass
>>> class Z(K1,K2,K3): pass
```

I think the result that Python 2.2 will give linearizations for Z is:`['Z', 'K1', 'C', 'K2', 'B', 'E', 'K3', 'D', 'A', 'object']`, however, the doc gives `L[Z,P22] = Z K1 K3 A K2 D B C E O`

and the doc said, this example is originally provided by Samuele Pedroni in [here](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2002-October/029035.html), and Samuele Pedroni's answer is the same as mine.

Is there anything I missed?

Comment: Why do you think Python 2.2 would give a different result? Did you try it?

Comment: @JeromeJ: I actually had left two remaining posts with the `mro` tag *for a reason*. :-) I cannot create a synonym without at least *some* posts still using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I think the result that Python 2.2 will give linearizations for Z is:['Z', 'K1', 'C', 'K2', 'B', 'E', 'K3', 'D', 'A', 'object']

Why do you think that?

A quick try:

```
Python 2.2 (#28, Dec 21 2001, 12:21:22) [MSC 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> class A(object): pass
...
>>> class B(object): pass
...
>>> class C(object): pass
...
>>> class D(object): pass
...
>>> class E(object): pass
...
>>> class K1(A,B,C): pass
...
>>> class K2(D,B,E): pass
...
>>> class K3(D,A):   pass
...
>>> class Z(K1,K2,K3): pass
...
>>> Z.__mro__
(<class '__main__.Z'>, <class '__main__.K1'>, <class '__main__.K3'>, <class '__m
ain__.A'>, <class '__main__.K2'>, <class '__main__.D'>, <class '__main__.B'>, <c
lass '__main__.C'>, <class '__main__.E'>, <type 'object'>)
>>>
```

So the MRO for `Z` is `Z K1 K3 A K2 D B C E object`, so the docs seem to be correct.

Comment: Then my next question is why the order is this? What is the algrothim about MRO in python 2.2, not the left-right dfs of the class
hierarchy?

Comment: It seems that your python interpreter is not like mine which I installed in VirtualBox (Windows XP), when I input `z.__mro__`, the interpreter says `class z has no attribute '__mro__'`

Comment: Maybe you'll find this interesting, then: [The History of Python - Method Resolution Order](http://python-history.blogspot.de/2010/06/method-resolution-order.html)

Comment: @DepreYon Are you sure you're using new-style classes?